# watir goto method as param

Tags: ruby, watir

I have the following code:

```
class Test
  def initialize(browser)
    @browser = browser
  end

  def init
    @browser.element(css: ".app").wait_until(&:present?)
  end
end
```

Run like this:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, headless: true)
test = Teste.new(browser.goto('https://www.google.com))
teste.init
```

And I got this error:

> undefined method `element' for #String:0x00007fe29d10f978
> (NoMethodError)

It seems that passing the goto method as a parameter doesn't work.
How can I solve that?

Comment: You are not passing browser variable, you are passing the return value of b.goto.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work

```
class Test
def initialize(browser)
  @browser = browser
end

 def init
   @browser.goto("https://www.google.com")
   @browser.element(css: ".app").wait_until(&:present?)
 end
end


browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, headless: true)
test = Test.new(browser)
test.init()
```